# The Video file format in xml

Tags: android, video

I am having a problem adding a video file to my project. When I copy the file to raw files, the icon type shows like it is an xml file instead of a question mark, and when I try to call the file I can't because the file type changed from media file to xml file.

I tried to use many video files but the problem persists.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Comment: Can you please be more clear ? It looks like you say that your media file is changed to xml file !! Please explain your steps so that everyone will be able to help you more..

Comment: Thank you ,I have tried to add any video to my app but when I added it the icon for the video file shown in resource file like a xml layout instead of media file .

Comment: In which folder are you placing your media files ?

Comment: @San in raw file resource

Comment: It would be helpful to give enough information for someone else to replicate the issue. You may find reading the StackOverflow guide on [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) useful in this.

Comment: @RobinJamesKerrison thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am able to get your question right, you are not able to play a video file.
There are several ways one can play a video in android and the easiest would be to place a video file (.mp4 extension recommended) in a raw folder (create one if you don't have it) inside of your res folder.  And please get a video from [here](http://www.law.duke.edu/cspd/contest/finalists/viewentry.php?file=docandyou).

Place the video in your raw folder as mentioned above.

You can play the video by placing a `VideoView` in your xml.

**CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
   android:paddingLeft="2px"
   android:paddingRight="2px"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:paddingTop="2px"
   android:paddingBottom="2px"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

      <VideoView 
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:id="@+id/VideoView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA CODE:**

```
 VideoView view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
 String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
 view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
 view.start();
```

where video_file in `R.raw.video_file` is your video file name. If your video file name is `boom.mp4` then you can write `R.raw.boom`.

Comment: Thank you I don't have any problem with code the problem is when I add any video file in the raw the android studio can't define the video as media file it's define as a xml file

Comment: That's weird, can you post a screenshot of the media file showing an extension of xml file ?

Comment: refer to the post the number 1 is a shortcut for the image

Comment: Right click on the res folder, choose New->Android resource directory. In the directory name, give 'raw' and also choose raw under resource type. Create your raw folder by following the above steps and then paste your mp4 file.

Comment: Thank you I will try it again

Comment: Are you not able to play your video ?